# Can I select a property and a sub-property in a Powershell one-liner

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a JSON array of MAC addresses and associated IP addresses of DHCP leases from a Windows DHCP server using PowerShell.

Using this:
`Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 192.168.0.0 | Where-Object {$_.AddressState -eq "ActiveReservation"} |  Select-Object -Property ClientId,IPAddress | ConvertTo-Json`

I get this output:

```json
[
  {
    "ClientId": "00-11-22-33-44-55",
    "IPAddress": {
      "Address": 12345678,
      "AddressFamily": 2,
      "ScopeId" : null,
      "IPAddressToString": "192.168.0.2"
    }
  },
  {
    "ClientId": "00-11-22-33-44-66",
    "IPAddress": {
      "Address": 12345679,
      "AddressFamily": 2,
      "ScopeId" : null,
      "IPAddressToString": "192.168.0.3"
    }
  }
]
```

But I only want the ClientId and value of IPAddressToString, not the other properties:

```json
[
  {
    "ClientId": "00-11-22-33-44-55",
    "IPAddressToString": "192.168.0.2"
  },
  {
    "ClientId": "00-11-22-33-44-66",
    "IPAddressToString": "192.168.0.3"
  }
]
```

Is this possible in a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 192.168.0.0 | Where-Object { $_.AddressState -eq "ActiveReservation" } |  Select-Object -Property ClientId, @{Name = "Address"; Expression = { $_.IpAddress.IPAddressToString} } | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this returned json is an array, I think you need to loop through the elements like

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 192.168.0.0 | 
    Where-Object {$_.AddressState -eq "ActiveReservation"} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Select-Object ClientId, @{Name = 'IPAddress'; Expression = {$_.IPAddress.IPAddressToString}}
    } | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "ClientId":  "00-11-22-33-44-55",
        "IPAddress":  "192.168.0.2"
    },
    {
        "ClientId":  "00-11-22-33-44-66",
        "IPAddress":  "192.168.0.3"
    }
]
```

<sup>P.S. You *can* write this as a one-liner, but that would make the code harder to read, easier to make mistakes and there is nothing to be gained by writing LONG lines of code. You'll make things only more difficult for yourself by doing that</sup>